# How to merge elevation from a raster image onto a shape road network with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, merge, elevation, shapefile

I have a shape file with Stockholms road network and a raster image with elevation data from the same area.

**Is there any way to merge the two somehow, either by adding the slope direction as positive or negative numeric values through an extra column in the attribute data or in any other magic way?**

The purpose would be to calculated shortest path with regard to the elevation, to be able to avoid unnecessary uphill climbs.

I work with QGIS and pgRouting so an answer compatible with that would preferable, but other solutions are welcome as well!